# Primary key value after insertion of row in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, primary-key, insert-update

In SQL Server 2005 I am inserting a row into a table using  a stored procedure and I want to fetch the new primary key value just  after inserting that row. I am using following approach to get primary key value after insertion row

```
Create Proc Sp_Test
@testEmail varchar(20)=null,-- Should be Unique
@testName varchar(20)=null -- Should be Unique
as

begin

insert into tableTest  (testUserEmail,testUserName)values (@testValue,@testName)

select MAX(ID) from tableTest --ID is Primary Key
```

--or

```
select ID from tableTest  where  testUserEmail =@testValue and testUserName = @testName
```

--or

```
select  SCOPE_IDENTITY() as ID

end
```

Please suggest me which approach is better to perform described task.

Answer (score 5):

By all means - use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` if your `ID` column is an `INT IDENTITY` - **only** that will give you the correct results!

The first approach with the `MAX(ID)` will fail terribly if you have multiple clients inserting rows almost at the same time - you'll get false results back. Don't use that!

The third approach might fail if another entry with the same values for E-Mail and name already exists.

Also, as a side-note: you should **never** use `sp_` as your prefix! This is a Microsoft-reserved prefix and has downsides in terms of performance - use something else.

Comment: Thanks marc_s fro reply...U told "The first approach with the MAX(ID) will fail terribly if you have multiple clients inserting rows almost at the same time - you'll get false results back. Don't use that!"......But i have 1 question in my mind that if multiple user inserting row than  the set of sql statements will execute separately for each    clients .until procedure end block

Comment: @Shailesh Sahu: **NO!** If you don't have any explicit transactions (and you don't), then the `INSERT` statement in itself is an implicit transaction. Once that's run, other clients can read the values - if you have hundreds of clients inserting simultaneously, you're guaranteed to get wrong results... and even if you have a transaction - others might be reading `WITH (NOLOCK)` or other mechanisms and get back false values....

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Identity column as primary key you should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

You could also use the [OUTPUT Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to return the ID.

```
insert into tableTest(testUserEmail,testUserName) 
output inserted.ID
values (@testValue, @testName)
```